# Not clear on how this Prolog depth first search (DFS) method code works

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

Today a teacher gave us this code on prolog:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, void, void), [X]) :- !.
dfs_paths(tree(X, L, _R), [X|Xs])   :- dfs_paths(L, Xs).
dfs_paths(tree(X, _L, R), [X|Xs])   :- dfs_paths(R, Xs).
    
tree(A) :-
   A = tree(i,
          tree(A,
          tree(la,void,void),
          tree(sa,void,void)
       ),
   tree(b,
      tree(lb,void,void),
      tree(sb,void,void)
    )).
```

He told us that code is a way to work DFS method on prolog, but we didn't receive more information about how the code works on each line.

I'm a newbie using prolog and I'm trying to understand this code

Thanks guys!

Update: this is the tree

[image: Binary tree]

Comment: That's some wild/irresponsible teacher....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently we want to all the paths from the tree root to one of its leaves by backtracking.

First, the declaration of the tree has to be corrected:

The tree is a term built/written as follows (N.B. every text element is *lowercase* otherwise we would be writing down variables instead of constants):

```
tree(i,
     tree(a,
          tree(la,void,void),
          tree(sa,void,void)),
     tree(b,
          tree(lb,void,void),
          tree(sb,void,void))).
```

And we can store is simply by declaring a *fact* that holds this tree as argument

```
tree_storage(
   tree(i,
        tree(a,
             tree(la,void,void),
             tree(sa,void,void)),
        tree(b,
             tree(lb,void,void),
             tree(sb,void,void)))
).
```

Now the "visit code"

```
dfs_paths(+Tree,?Path)
```

which builds (or verifies) a path `Path` through the tree given by `Tree`.

If the first argument looks like a leaf node (i.e. is built using functor `tree` with 3 arguments, and the constant `void` on argument positions 2 and 3, the the path is just the name of the node:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, void, void), [X]).
```

There is no need to `cut` (`!`) at all.

Otherwise, if the left branch of the tree is non-`void`, then the possibility is offered to recursively generate a path by going down the left branch, and prepend the name of the root tree node, i.e. `X`. We don't care about visiting the right branch here. To make the compiler not complain, the placeholder for the right branch is written with a `_` in front:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, L, _R), [X|Xs]) :- dif(L,void), dfs_paths(L, Xs).
```

Otherwise, if the right branch of the tree is non-`void`, then the possibility is offered to recursively generate a path by going down the right branch, and prepend the name of the root tree node, i.e. `X`. We don't care about visiting the left branch here. To make the compiler not complain, the placeholder for the left branch is written with a `_` in front:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, _L, R), [X|Xs]) :- dif(R,void), dfs_paths(R, Xs).
```

Putting this together and adding a `format/2` statement to print what's going on, we see that Prolog tries all possibilites by applying the three rules to the "tree" term:

```
dfs_paths(tree(X, void, void), [X]) :-
   format("At leaf '~q'~n",[X]).
dfs_paths(tree(X, L, _R), [X|Xs]) :- 
   dif(L,void), 
   format("Going down left at inner node '~q'~n",[X]),
   dfs_paths(L, Xs).
dfs_paths(tree(X, _L, R), [X|Xs]) :- 
   dif(R,void),
   format("Going down right at inner node '~q'~n",[X]),
   dfs_paths(R, Xs).

tree_storage(
   tree(i,
        tree(a,
             tree(la,void,void),
             tree(sa,void,void)),
        tree(b,
             tree(lb,void,void),
             tree(sb,void,void)))
).

run(Path) :-
   tree_storage(Tree),    % Tree is our predefined tree
   dfs_paths(Tree,Path).   % A Path is some path through that tree
```

Now run this:

```
?- run(Path).
Going down left at inner node 'i'
Going down left at inner node 'a'
At leaf 'la'
Path = [i,a,la] ;
Going down right at inner node 'a'
At leaf 'sa'
Path = [i,a,sa] ;
Going down right at inner node 'i'
Going down left at inner node 'b'
At leaf 'lb'
Path = [i,b,lb] ;
Going down right at inner node 'b'
At leaf 'sb'
Path = [i,b,sb] ;
false.
```

Comment: Holy..... this is by far the best explanation that I've received. Thank U so much, U made me understand every line of this code.
i have learned something new today

One question more...

The variable Xs (I know that is the tail of the list) stores the path?

Comment: @ManuEsquivel It stores the path indeed. `Xs` is not a tail of a list, but is a list itself. It appears as the tail in a new list `[X|Xs]` which can be read as "this is a new list whereby we prepend `X` to another list `Xs`.